# What happens to my EC2 instance data (EBS) when I stop the instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Initially I have created an instance and installed HTTPD package in it.
Then I stopped it and later started it.

1. Public IP is changed.
2. HTTPD is still actively running.

My doubt is, with this change in Public IP was I allocated a different instance(VM) but with previous EBS?
Please Help! Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have the same instance but when you stop it your are allocated a new public IP.  If you associate an elastic IP with your instance then the IP will remain the same after a stop and restart.

Be careful on instance types that have "ephemeral" storage.  That is disk space that is local to the instance.  When you stop your instance your O/S is still there but the rest of the storage is new.  So if you store something local it will be gone.  Most smaller instances use EBS (elastic block storage) now so it's less of a problem but if it's not EBS then be careful.

Comment: "same instance" is a bit misleading here. You get a new virtual machine, running on different hardware, but the network attached storage (EBS) is still the same.

Comment: You're correct @MarkB but for all outward appearances it's the same instance. The instance metadata is the same (even the mac is the same), I can use the same credential to log in (i.e. the storage is the same) and so on. I know I get new hardware at least sometimes as I've had Amazon tell me that I need to stop and restart an instance because of an underlying issue but I generally don't care.